# How to base64 encode/decode binary files in python?

Tags: python, base64

I'm trying to encode and decode the same image file using python using following simple code. But every time output file is larger than input file and it can't open. What's the problem in this code?

```
import base64

with open("img.jpeg", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

    decoded_string = base64.b64decode(encoded_string)
    with open("test_img.jpeg", "w") as image_file2:
        image_file2.write(decoded_string);
```

Original file: https://filebin.ca/3j6aIDlWEYdV/img.jpeg 
Result file:  https://filebin.ca/3j6arBo85Lcg/test_img.jpeg

Comment: running this code locally produces an output file that's identical to the input file. Are you **sure** this is the code you're running?

Comment: Yes, I just copy pasted my code and I tested this several times. My python version is 2.7.13. Could it be the problem?

Comment: I'm running 2.7.13 too

Comment: Found the problem, problem is, it should be "wb" in the write file. If I change it back to just "w" then file is not readable, if I change it back to "wb" then its working again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing the write mode to `"wb"`. You're writing and reading as different formats right now.